# Ember: deactivate not called when transitioning from one route to another

Tags: ember.js

When you transition from index.html#/admin/authors/1/edit to index.html#/admin/authors/2/edit, deactivate on the route **is not called**.

When you transition from index.html#/admin/authors/1/edit to index.html#/admin/authors/new, deactivate on the route **is called**.

I would expect that in both cases deactivate is called ?

Is there another method at route level to detect that you switch from ../1/edit to ../2/edit ?

I need this in a master detail view (master is list with all authors, detail is form with textfields for each of the author properties).  If the users selects another author in the list and the previous author was modified without saving, I need to rollback the transaction or ask the user 'do you want to save changes ?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deactivate is not called in this case since the edit route is still active. To detect switching from ../1/edit to ../2/edit use the route's `willTransition` event. For example:

```
App.FormRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      if(!this.controller.get('canNavigate')) {
        alert('non-empty form!');
        transition.abort();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See this gist for more examples: https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589